# Install a hyphenation file for xetex

Tags: xetex, hyphenation

This is a beginner question: I need to use this hyphenation pattern: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xetex-greek

with xetex, how can I do to install it?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the `polyglossia` package?  The documentation is found here: [polyglossia](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia?lang=en) and works well for hyphenated greek

Comment: Yes, I use `\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}` but ancient greek hyphenation don'works.